# Toss a fair coin 30 times, what’s the expected value of the last digit of the number of Heads(e.g. H 16times, last digit is 6)?

Tags: probability

I know how to do these in a very tedious way using a binomial distribution, but is there a clever way to solve this without doing 31 binomial coefficients (with some equivalents)?

Comment: If you consider that the last digit of the expected value is $5$, and the symmetry, I think the answer is also $5$.  That would be a lot harder if it hadn't been symmetrical.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor I think you should make that an answer.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor What do you mean by the last digit of the expected value is 5? Like it is 5, 5.5, etc? How do you see this? I also now see the symmetry of probabilities between 1,2,3,4 and 9,8,7,6 respectively.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor That's almost true, but not quite. If $Y$ is the last digit, then it's true that $P(Y=3)=P(Y=7)$, etc, but $Y=0$ breaks the symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the number of heads, $Y= X \pmod {10}$ the last digit. $X$ is a binomial, its pmf $P_X$ is symmetrical around $X=15$.

Then, $P_Y$ is almost symmetrical around $Y=5$. For example:

$$ P_Y(3)=P_X(3)+P_X(13)+P_X(23)=P_X(7)+P_X(17)+P_X(27) =P_Y(7) $$

Regrettably, $Y=0$ breaks the symmetry. Let $U$ be the indicator variable of event $Y \ne 0$. What we know, then, is
$E[Y|U=1]=5$. Furthermore, $E[Y|U=0]=0$.

Then

$$E[Y] = E[E[Y|U]] = P_U(1) E[Y|U=1] + P_U(0) E[Y|U=0] = P_U(1) \,5 $$

and

$$P_U(1)=1 - 2(P_X(0) + P_X(10)) = 1- 2 \left(\frac{1}{2^{30}} + \frac{1}{2^{30}}  \binom{30}{10}\right)
$$
Hence
$$E[Y] = 4.720\dots$$

Answer (score 0):

First approach:  let $K$ be the number of heads.

The expected value of $K$ is $15$. So the last digit of that is $5$.

$P(K = 14) = P(K = 16)$, and so the part of the expected value based on those averages to $5$ as well since the last digits are $4$ and $6$.

Likewise for $13$ and $17$, $12$ and $18$, $11$ and $19$ average to $5$

$10$ and $20$ make a problem, in that they both have last digit $0$...but that just means that both terms contribute $0$ to the expected value.

Continuing, $9$ and $21$, $8$ and $22$, and so on also cancel, and finally $0$ and $30$ contribute nothing.

So the problem cases are $0$, $10$, $20$, and $30$.

We can solve this by considering the overall expected value as a weighted sum of all the parts that averaged to $5$, times the probability of getting one of those cases, and $0$ times the probability of getting $0,10,20$ or $30$

$$P(0) = 2^{-30} = P(30). $$
$$ P(10) = P(20) = {30 \choose 10} \cdot 2^{-30}$$
So the probability of getting any of those is $2\cdot \big(1 + {30 \choose 10}\big) \cdot 2^{-30}$ . The answer will be $5$ times $1-$that result.